# Update on blur the first time only

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can defer model updating until blur with `ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"`.  This prevents annoying the user with changing validation states while entering input the first time around.  However, when a user returns to a failed validation to revise it, the `updateOn: 'blur'` prevents the validation state from being updated when the user has fixed it (but before they leave the field).

How can I reset the `updateOn` option to allow the default model update schedule after one blur?

Comment: I removed my answer as it messed with the form state. I will post an update if I find a better solution.

Comment: @DougLuce, did the answer address your question?

Comment: Sorry, it does not.  See http://plnkr.co/edit/pZfO5JpZipjutTvcHwEE?p=preview for tasseKATT's attempt along the same lines.

Answer (score 0):

`ngModelOptions` directive [$evals its value](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.12/src/ng/directive/ngModel.js#L1218), but doesn't observe it for changes. In other words, you **cannot** achieve what you are looking for with something like the following:

```
<input ng-model="foo" ng-model-options="fooOptions">
```

and then change it in the controller:

```
$scope.fooOptions = {updateOn: "blur"};
$scope.changeOptions = function(){
  $scope.fooOptions = {updateOn: "default"};
}
```

For simple cases, you could add another variable that changes how you show validation messages:

```
<form name="form1">
   <input name="foo"
          ng-model="foo" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'default'}"
          ng-blur="startShowingErrors = true" minlength="3">

   <span ng-show="startShowingErrors && form1.foo.$invalid">invalid entry</span>
</form>
```

But, if you want the actual form state not update, then you'd need another directive as a facade to `ngModelOptions` to cause a `$compile` on every change.